# GitHub returning 403

Tags: github

All of a sudden this morning I'm getting a 403 from GitHub when trying to push.

> remote: You must verify your email address.
>
> remote: See https://github.com/settings/emails.

When I visit the URL there's no indication that anything is wrong:

> Your primary GitHub email address will be used for account-related notifications (e.g. account changes and billing receipts) as well as any web-based GitHub operations (e.g. edits and merges).
>
> myemail@mydomain.com Primary Public

I've never seen this issue before, has anyone come across it?

Comment: Is your email address verified? That's what the error says.

Comment: Is your email address configured in git the same as your github email address? I would be surprised if they enforce that, but you never know. Otherwise, lodge a github support ticket, if your email address really *is verified*, then it's a problem on their end.

Comment: @Rob No, that is not so. You can push commits made by any committer name/email.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/verifying-your-email-address/

Comment: voting to close as off topic now (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): **Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced**

Answer (score 0):

OK, the issue went away by itself this morning with no input from me, no idea why it happened.

Comment: voting to close as off topic now (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): **Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced**